# What is the proper way to upload file and send it as a string to the server using Express?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, file, pdf, react-hooks

**Overview:**

I have a `react` component that I want to upload a PDF file and send to the server without using any libraries. The uploader will be able to upload a single file or multiple files, depending on the user. The parameter type for the file is  `integer($int64)`.

**Process:**

1. It has a feature to select multiple files and I store the files in the state with the type `IPDF`.
2. In the method `upload`, my plan is to loop over the `attachments` and hit the endpoint. I also add the following properties:

**Possibilities (Using No Libraries):**

I'm new to the following, so this is just what I have encountered in my research and I'm not entirely confident in using them.

- `FormData`?
- `Blob`?
- `base64`?
- Using a `react` hook?
- ?

**PDFUploader.tsx:**

```js
// Imports: Dependencies
import React, { useState } from 'react';

// TypeScript Type: PDF
interface IPDF {
  fileName: string;  
  file: File;
}

// React Component: PDF Uploader
const PDFUploader = ({ documentId, listingId }): JSX.Element => {
  // React Hooks: State
  const [attachments, setAttachments] = useState<Array<IPDF>>([]);

  // Upload
  const upload = async (): Promise<void> => {
    // CRSF Token
    const crsfToken: Element | null = document.querySelector('meta[name="crsf-token"]');

    // Iterate Over Attachments
    for (let i: number = 0; i < attachments.length; i++) {
      // Fetch: Request Options
      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          // Header Name 'crsf-token' Depends On The Server
          'crsf-token': crsfToken?.getAttribute('content') || '';
        },
        body: {
          listingId,
          documentId,
          formName: attachments[i].fileName,
          file: attachments[i].file, // QUESTION: HOW CAN I CONVERT THE FILE TO A STRING TO UPLOAD TO THE SERVER. THE PARAMETER TYPE FOR THE FILE IS `integer($int64)`, BUT I DON'T KNOW EXACTLY WHAT THAT MEANS
          templateTypeId: 3,
          areFieldsNotRequired: false,
        };
      };

      // Fetch: POST
      fetch('https://www.test.com/api/form-upload', requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data) => alert('File successfully uploaded.');
        .catch((error) => alert(error));
    }
  };

  render (
    <div>
      {/* Uploader Code Here */} 
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: [What about an input with type="file"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file), unless I'm missing something?

Comment: I guess you could also encode your data as `multipart/form-data`

Comment: @BrendanBond I'm pretty new to form-data, can you elaborate on how that works versus a blob or base64?

Comment: Did you read the link? It's all there